# Talkback doesn't announce in when we use TAB to navaigate to next field

Tags: android, accessibility

Let us assume that I have a TextView in between two EditText's.

TextView gets VISIBLE only when certain conditions pass after evaluating text an EditText on FocusChange.

And when I make it VISIBLE with a custom dynamic text I call textView.announceForAccessibility(dynamic string) to announce the content.

This works fine when I use TAP gesture or SWIPE gesture to move away from editTextUnderEvaluation to another anotherEditText. announceForAccessibility announces my dynamic string.

But when I use a keyboard and use TAB to move from editTextUnderEvaluation to anotherEditText, it doesn't announce my dynamic string.

I have tried using

> 1. accessibilityLiveRegion
> 2. accessibilityTraversalAfter / Before
> 3. Creating and sending a new accessibility ANNOUNCE event

None of these worked.

My assumption - When I use TAB to move from editTextUnderEvaluation to anotherEditText the android virtual keyboard talkback is interrupting my announcement. Is there a way I can change the keyboard talkback to polite mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and a solution. Answering it for a reference.

When you use TAB to navigate from one edit text to another edit text, EditText component has an announcement of type TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED which reads out "Editing edittext ...". This is a high priority announcement and it interrupts all announcements that should happen before it. As my text view announcement comes before the TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED for second edit text, this also got interrupted.

So it was not the Keyboard which interrupted the speech as I assumed.

What I did to solve it was to Override onInitializeAccessibilityEvent() method in EditText and skip the event for TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED and send my own custom announcement for this event.